# s.tk url for Biology SE

Tags: feature-request, status-planned, url

> [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795/157163)

Shouldn't Biology.SE have a shorthand URL like the rest of the sites in beta? For example:

s.tk/biology or s.tk/bio should redirect to biology.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10):

Well we can use the form to request one if we first decide which to go for.

Personally I think `s.tk/bio` makes more sense as the whole purpose is to create a shorter URL - using biology would seem to be self defeating :L

**This has now been requested.**

Comment: Hmm, still not functional.

Comment: And still not so. Have they stopped adding new urls?

Comment: @fileunderwater They only add them after the site graduates out of beta. http://s.tk/christianity was only added a month after graduation but it was in beta for over 2 years.